# UIView Animation for ImageView in ios

Tags: ios, user-interface

i Have requirement were i have to animate image view from current position to full screen in grid view. i made images into Grid view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];        
    for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {

        [imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i]]];
        NSLog(@"imagesArray:%@", imagesArray);               
    }

    float horizontal = 20.0;
    float vertical = 20.0;

    for(int i=0; i<[imagesArray count]; i++)
    {
        if((i%3) == 0 && i!=0)
        {
            horizontal = 20.0;
            vertical = vertical + 220.00 + 20.0;
        }

        imagesView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(horizontal, vertical, 310.0, 220.00)];
        imagesView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [imagesView setImage:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        imagesView.tag = i;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

        [imagesView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        [self.view addSubview:imagesView];
        horizontal = horizontal + 310.0 + 20.0;
      }

}
```

here i have created grid view with images, like i have 10 images. i made 3x3 grid view.

next i have add tap gesture to it and i am getting the image view position by calling with tag

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
        UIView *piece = recognizer.view;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            piece.frame = CGRectMake(piece.frame.origin.x, piece.frame.origin.y, 1000, 700);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

    }
```

Can you say me how to make image view animate from current position to full screen by tapping on it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding the views to `self.view` of your view controller, you can assume that `self.view` is occupying the entire screen of the device. Therefore, you can animate to its bounds:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    piece.frame = self.view.bounds;
} completion:nil];
```

Note that if `piece` must have a parent view that spans across the entire screen so that your inner view won't be clipped during animation.

Comment: how to apply padding say 100px around the image on all sides

Comment: You can use `CGRectInset`: `piece.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 100, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

This code will help u to add the animation effect like zoom your imageview that your are expecting. You need to customize once the animation is over show the full screen image view.

```
-(void)addZoomAnimationToZoomViewController:(UIImageView *)zoomView
{
    CABasicAnimation *zoomAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    [zoomAnimation setDuration:0.8];
    [zoomAnimation setRepeatCount:1];
    [zoomAnimation setFromValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1]];
    [zoomAnimation setToValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0] ];
    [zoomAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[zoomView layer] addAnimation:zoomAnimation forKey:@"zoom"];
}
```